# SASS: Deleted styles from SASS still showing in generated CSS?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

Can you delete markups from a generated css file using sass?

**For example, I have this on my scss file:**

```
body{ background:$dark; }
```

**My generated CSS file will look like this:**

```
body{ background: #000; }
```

So what will happen if I delete that line of code in sass? (not commented but completely deleted)

So far, what happens with my project is that after I compile, the generated css file retains the markup that I've made earlier. 
So my CSS file still have this line even if I deleted it on my scss file:

```
body{ background: #000; }
```

Is this normal? or is it an error in my compiler? 
Can sass only create,edit or overwrite an existing markup in CSS and it cannot delete it? In other words, once the markups are generated in CSS, you can only modify them and you have to manually remove the line of codes in css if you decide to delete it?

Comment: what compiler do you use?

Comment: I'm using gulp.

I just want to know if the generated CSS markups can still be deleted in within SASS. For example I added a background: #000; to the body tag.. but decided to remove the background:#000 code completely, I can do it within sass but the generated CSS file stays the same - background:#000; will still appear within the body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete markups using your scss file but you can override properties of markups. You can only remove markups by editing your html files. That said, any change made to the scss will indeed reflect into the css file, you are right on this.

Comment: Thanks ! that's all i need to know. I'm fairly new with SASS and I'm still trying to structure my files, so its inevitable for me to add and delete markups, but its good to know what SASS can and cannot do, then I would know where to locate the markups that I need to remove. I'm trying to give you an up vote but I guess my rating is too low to do that.

Comment: So if you are using ionic, just use ionic markups or common HTML markups to structure your files and use css to design it 'in depth' ! Sass is just here to help with css (i.e assign a specific color to a tag, as explained in the Ionic scss file) and to be compiled into a normal css file.

Comment: Thank you, I have actually been looking for a guide on how to design an app in depth with ionic sass and css but I couldn't find any. I'm very familiar with css but I'm still new with sass and ionic so the workflow for me is a little confusing. For example if I want to do extensive customization that's not based on material design, how do I proceed with it? My instinct is telling me to learn the proper workflow with SASS but it would be quicker for me to just go into the css file and do the modifications there..

Comment: To me and from what I understand, I guess you would have to re design the entire thing according to your preferences. And so, overriding a lot of properties in css. Im currently building/designing an app that has several layouts that looks different from the original 'Ionic style' so I have to override and add a lot of classes myself.

Comment: To me, Sass is just a tool to help you going faster but it won't replace working in 'plain css' ! But to be honest, I don't want to confuse you about Sass since I'm just making a little use of it (re use of variables or just watch files so I don't have to reload the page each time a change is made, but that's more a gulp than a Sass thing here I guess) and most of my work is just css and overriding things. (sorry for the long para)

Comment: Thanks guys! these are very helpful inputs!
I actually just finished structuring my scss files. What I did is that I made a separate sass file for my deep customizations which generates its own stylesheet then I just added the link to the index file: for example (styles.scss: styles.css). This method makes it easier for me to find and delete unwanted markups or duplicates within CSS because it's separate from the main ionic.app.css file (its just a little more neat). Then I decided that all of the simple ionic customization such as layout or tab bar colors will still be within ionic.app.scss.

Comment: I also discovered a sass feature called mixins... and I'm obsessing over it!! it's so cool.

Comment: Looks like you already have a way through :D I may need to be a bit more curious about sass features ahah don't have much time.. but for now I get what I want so its ok :)

Comment: Oh man, don't wanna look greedy but could you mark my answer as accepted ? So I have the ability to comment everywhere :D

Comment: Yeah I've been wanting to do that, but I'm fairly new with stockoverflow, how do I do it - I should probably just google it XD